# Notepad++ how to find and replace partially within single line

Tags: notepad++

i want to replace only specific part of the line.

Below is the example:

```
OPPO|||CPH1931|||Jl. ABC No.1,A,E
OPPO|||CPH1931|||Jl. DEF No.2,X,Y
OPPO|||CPH1931|||JL. GHI No.3,Z,A
```

And below is the result that i wanted. Notice there is a double quotation mark "" after the last |||.

```
OPPO|||CPH1931|||"Jl. ABC No.1,A,E"
OPPO|||CPH1931|||"Jl. DEF No.2,X,Y"
OPPO|||CPH1931|||"JL. GHI No.3,Z,A"
```

Is it possible to do this with RegEx?
If yes, how would i do that?

Thanks before.

Comment: Yes, that might be possible. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: im stuck with the fact i cannot exclude the rest of the line. If i tried using \|\|\|.*\r\n, it will select everything instead the one thats near the CRLF that i want to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the fact that `.*` is greedy and will not match a newline character (by default). So:

Find what: `(.*\|\|\|)(.*)`
Replace with: `\1"\2"`
⦿ Regular expression     ▢ `.` matches newline (not checked!)

<kbd>Replace All</kbd>

### Explanation

- `.*` greedily matches any character (except newlines) any number of times.
- `.*\|\|\|` matches as many characters as possible until an occurrence of `|||`. As `.*` is greedy, this means the **last** `|||` occurrence on the current line will be included here. Any previous occurrences of `|||` on the same line will already have been absorbed in the `.*` part.
- `(.*\|\|\|)` puts that match in a capture group so later it can be referenced with `\1`.
- `(.*)` will match any remaining characters on the same line in a second capture group, which can be referenced with `\2`
- `\1"\2"` will reproduce the two capture groups, and adds literal double-quotes around what was captured in the second capture group.

Comment: wow this works perfectly. Could you explain the logic behind it if you don't mind?

Comment: Added an explanation in the answer.